# How to maintain multipart meshes

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I have done a reasonable amount of modeling in Blender, but am just starting to get into animation. In the past when I was modeling things I would tend to keep things as a lot of separate objects which makes editing different parts fairly easy. But getting into animation it seems that in order to use armatures you typically attach the armature to a single mesh. Assuming that is true my question is if I join a bunch of objects together are the ways of still being able to select the parts again in Edit mode?

I realize obviously that I can lasso the chunks and/or shift-select pieces. I am looking for whether or not are techniques that allow the merged parts to still maintain any of their original selectability. Is this something vertex groups can be used for? Some brilliant addon I haven't discovered?

I am using 2.91.

Comment: You can define vertex groups. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html?highlight=vertex%20groups

Comment: susu makes a good point, if you want to "join" the objects, you can first define vertex groups that contain all vertices from each object, and then join them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Joining the mesh objects into one, you can keep them separate if you wish.   Here I show two spheres that were then bound to an armature (armature modifier).  They respond to the appropriate nearby bones in pose mode.  This is how I might control both a character and possible control cloths (instead of with cloth modifier, although you can get "character bleeds through clothing" effects).  Several child objects could be parented to a master parent, but you'd have to experiment with side effects.

[image]